# no puedo interar una List en c# y no puedo hacer un cast

Tags: c#

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]la verdad es que ya probé de muchas maneras y no se como recorrerlo
creo que necesito decirle al operador de que una Lista de tipo BranchDT pero no se como hacerlo en internet no hay mucha info si alguno sabe porfavor necesito ayuda

Comment: podrías mostrarnos donde esta fallando tu código.

Comment: perdon, ahi esta eso intente

Comment: Duda estas declarando la lista ahi?? por que las listas no se declaran de esa forma, o que estas tratando de hacer

Comment: tengo una lista que viene desde el cms de umbraco y las lista se lllama BranchDT

Comment: Vas a tener que recorrer el elemento de BranchDT que es un DataTransferObject, y ahí vas convirtiendo lo que necesites. PD: Utilicé UmbracoCMS durante buen tiempo.

Comment: Seria bueno que compartieras tu código en lugar de subir una imagen...

Answer (score 0):

Posiblemente no estés definiendo bien la lista. Prueba con:

```
List<BranchDt> Lista = new List<BranchDt>();
```